# Is there a simple way to use Dependency Injection on my connections?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ninject

I'm looking for a way to inject my connections into my repositories. I tried to inject the `SqlConnection` using the `IDBConnection`, but I got some problems when `NInject` tries to deactivate the connection, the event is never called. And I cannot figure out how to inject the connection string into my repositories.

Could someone provide me a suggestion?

Comment: You will have to provide more information and probably a code sample.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I use NInject to perform the Dependency Injection of my projects. I usually end with the configuration below:

Simple Factory Interface

```
public interface IDbConnectionFactory
{
    IDbConnection CreateConnection();
}
```

Factory Implementation

```
public class SqlConnectionFactory : IDbConnectionFactory
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public SqlConnectionFactory(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public IDbConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        conn.Open();
        return conn;
    }
}
```

NInject Config:

```
Bind<IDbConnectionFactory>()
    .To<SqlConnectionFactory>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString",
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnection"].ConnectionString);
```

Example of a repository:

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly IDbConnectionFactory _dbConnectionFactory;

    public UserRepository(IDbConnectionFactory dbConnectionFactory)
    {
        _dbConnectionFactory = dbConnectionFactory;
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> List()
    {
        using (var dbConnection = _dbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection())
        {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I always let the ADO.NET take care of connection pooling. So I open and close the connection every single time that I need to perform a database operation.

This approach is working for me and is very simple as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: The complete example I was looking for. I will accept the answer as soon as SO allow me. Thank you dude.

Comment: so if you wanted to share the connection across requests, for use in a transaction, how would you go about doing it?

Comment: In transaction based scenarios I use a unit of work pattern. And not just a connection factory.

Comment: I'm still not getting it, if your UOW used this repository and the above List method it would end up opening a new connection?

Comment: Not really. The repository would receive the UOW in place of the connection factory. The UOW would be now responsible for opening/closing/committing....Inside the List method you need to get the connection from the UOW and not create a new one. Does it make sense?

Comment: @gustavodidomenico Would it be better to use a singleton in this example?

Comment: @LiverpoolOwen, I think that you mean use your container to inject the same instance every time you request an instance. Then, you can configure the binding to use the `InSingletonScope` configuration of `NInject`. I don't recommend using the regular singleton approach using the static field to hold the instance reference.

Comment: @gustavodidomenico thanks for the reply, why would you not recommend this? Does this affect performance negatively?

Comment: When i say singleton I mean for the connection factory not the actual IDBconnection

Comment: I also meant the factory. The reason is not about performance to be honest, but from a maintainability, operational, testability and readability perspectives. If you have your dependency lifecycle managed by an IoC container, you should delegate this to it.